# WebView: status code 404 even when page loads fine in browser

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView in my app where I have overridden the following method and whenever error 404 comes, I load a different url-

```
public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            //load another url
        }
```

The problem I am facing is the first url returns 404 and then in this block the second url loads.

But this block gets called again and again even when the page exists and works fine on browser.

I found some hint from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098797/8409500) but did not understand how to handle it. Is there any way know that status code 404 is received when entire webpage not found or when some element in webpage not found.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us the code which loads the website.

Comment: @ReneFerrari I have just loaded the url - `webview.loadUrl(secondaryUrl);`

Comment: how does the url look like?

Comment: and have you set any webview settings?

Comment: @ReneFerrari I can't share the url and for webview settings I have used the following lines-
`webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);`

Comment: maybe enable DOM helps?

Comment: No it does not help.

Comment: I have similar question. No matter whatever URL you load, onReceivedHttpError always give 404 even when paid is loaded and making real 404 handling impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in this answer- [Android WebView : onreceivedHttpError statusCode == 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432583/android-webview-onreceivedhttperror-statuscode-404).
 The onReceivedHttpError callback will be called for any resource (iframe, image, etc), not just for the main page. Thus, it is recommended to perform the minimum required work in this callback. I just remove this callback and my app works well now.